# Ansible: with_dict to access particular key for the dictionary created from json file

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I am fairly new to ansible, and trying to explore the dictionary plug options.
below is my playbook, I am trying to convert a json file to dictionary using the from_json module and then i am want to print particular keys only. 
Not able to achieve the 2nd part.

here's the code:

```
hosts: localhost
vars:
  jsonVar: "{{ lookup('file', 'ConfigData.json') | from_json }}"

tasks:
  - name: print numbers
    debug: msg=" {{ jsonVar.cpsSiteName }}"
    debug: msg=" {{ jsonVar.dmsDataCacheAddress }}"
    debug: msg=" {{ jsonVar.htsHttpClientIdleConnectionTimeout }}"
    debug: msg=" {{ jsonVar.palConsulServerList }}"
    debug: msg=" {{ jsonVar.prsMaxIncoReqProcTime }}"
    debug: msg=" {{ jsonVar.prsMaxNumberOfExecutedScriptInstructions }}"
    debug: msg=" {{ jsonVar.prsmschapv2Password }}"
```

the output only displays the last debug statement.
Eager to know if there is smarter way to access particular variable from the converted dictionary and then print it at the output.

I tried using with_items, but doesn't work.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Below is a sample json file:

```
    root@BVSETL04:/etc/ansible# less ConfigData.json 
    {
      "appSupCommonPullSendProxyAuthInfo":0,
      "appSupCommonPullSendWebAuthInfo":0,
      "appSupDdcSupervisionEnabled":1,
      "appSupDdcSupervisionInterval":15,
      "appSupDdcSupervisionMaxNoOfFailures":4,
      "appSupDNS_number_consequtive_failures":5,
      "appSupDNS_supervision_interval":60,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your playbook syntax is incorrect – there is only one task defined (each task should start as a new list item (dash symbol)).

Not sure what your problem is, but to print all vars with different tasks you can use:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    jsonVar: "{{ lookup('file', 'ConfigData.json') | from_json }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: msg=" {{ jsonVar.cpsSiteName }}"
    - debug: msg=" {{ jsonVar.dmsDataCacheAddress }}"
    - debug: msg=" {{ jsonVar.htsHttpClientIdleConnectionTimeout }}"
    # etc...
```